# FFMPEG settings for MP4 encoding with MPEG4 not x264

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg

i use this command line on Windows to encode all my videos :

```
ffmpeg -i MyInputFile.wmv -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -c:a libvo_aacenc -q:a 100 MyOutPutFile.mp4
```

All these originals videos are in .wmv and they have a bitrate of 1200kb/s.

I have to use MPEG4 to read the encoded videos on Android / iOS. With x264 it doesn't work, i have a black screen and audio only.

The command line works fine, but my output files are too big ( bigger than .wmv files, but MPEG4 is better normally ). How can i change my settings ? Select the bitrate ? i'm trying this but it doesn't work, the bitrate is still too high :

```
ffmpeg -i TestBitRate.wmv -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -b 500k -c:a libvo_aacenc -q:a 100 TestBitRate.mp4
```

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: I recommend getting H.264 videos working before resorting to MPEG-4 Part 2 video. These devices should be able to decode at least Baseline profile, level 3.0. If you want help with that then show your `ffmpeg` command that "doesn't work" and the complete console output. Also, questions not about programming are offtopic here and `ffmpeg` cli questions are better suited for [su]. You can get a moderator to migrate your question with the flag link.